# django-modeltranslation causes django unable to access database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-modeltranslation

I have a django rest framework project already going with some models already created, and I am trying to add django-modeltranslation to the project. I followed the process as specified in django-modeltranslation documentation, but applications stop working after making migrations with django-modeltranslation modifications.

Everytime I try to access de database, wether through the admin page or the django rest framework page, I get an error with the applications I have added `transalation.py` file to. Applications without it continue working.

This is my model:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, verbose_name=_('Name'))
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5, verbose_name=_('Code'))
    calling_code = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Calling code'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Country')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Countries')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my `translation.py`

```
@register(models.Country)
class CountryTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('name',)
```

And this is the whole traceback of the error I get:

```
Internal Server Error: /es/general/countries/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 40, in list
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 74, in get_queryset
    queryset = queryset.all()
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 829, in all
    return self._chain()
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1156, in _chain
    obj = self._clone()
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/modeltranslation/manager.py", line 234, in _clone
    return super(MultilingualQuerySet, self)._clone(**kwargs)
TypeError: _clone() got an unexpected keyword argument '_rewrite'
[05/Jun/2018 15:54:13] "GET /es/general/countries/ HTTP/1.1" 500 99097
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please post the _full_ traceback. This being said, it looks like your versions of Django (or DRF) and model-translations are not compatible.

Comment: I added the traceback in the body of the question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please check your django version vs this : http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling the error ( ;) ) led me to https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation/issues/436 – if I'm assuming correctly, you're using Django 2.0, and no released version of django-modeltranslation supports it yet.

Comment: Oh yes,I saw it. Thanks a lot